# ASP.NET MVC custom user roles/profiles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am creating a website using asp.net mvc model. When you create an mvc application asp.net automatically creates roles/profiles for user and admins (as far as i know) and corresponding tables in sql server database.

I a need a new profile/role names "sponsor" that has all the benefits of users/admins (like authorization etc).

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually by default there are no roles defined in the ASP.NET forms authentication database that you get when you use ASP.NET MVC, however it's very easy to define them.  All you need to do is open your project in Visual Studio and click the "Project" menu and click "ASP.NET Configuration" at the bottom.  From that system you can set up any roles and users you need.